# Conditional expectation of uniform given normal

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Let $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, $Y \sim U(-\alpha, \alpha)$ and $Z = X - Y$.
Assume $Y$ and $Z$ are independent. Note that $X$ and $Y$ are necessarily dependent.

What is $\mathbb{E}[Z|X]$?

---

What I've tried

$$
\mathbb{E}[Z|X](x) = \frac{1}{p_X(x)} \int z \, p_Y(x-z)p_Z(z) \mathrm{d}z
$$

I don't know what $p_Z(z)$ is. I've tried getting it from the characteristic functions
$$ p_Z(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int e^{-itz} \Phi_X(t)/\Phi_Y(t) \mathrm{d} t $$
but the integral looks intimidating.

It would be nicer to beat the integral for $\mathbb{E}[Z|X]$ out of $\Phi_Z(t)$ without finding a closed form for $p_Z(z)$...

Comment: As $Y+Z = X$ so I doubt that $Y$ and $Z$ can be independent.

Comment: How can $Z$ and $Y$ be independent? Did you mean $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify

Comment: I still don't think it is possible to construct $X,Y$ such that $Y$ and $Z$ are independent. Suppose $Y$ and $Z$ are independent, then $cov(Y^n, (X-Y)^m) = 0$ for all $m,n \in \Bbb N^*$. For example, with $m = n =1$, you must have $E(XY) = E(Y^2)$ and you will get the first equation $f_1(\mu, \sigma, \alpha) = 0$. By changing $m,n$ (for example $(m,n) = (1,2), (2, 1) , ...$ you will get other equations $f_k(\mu, \sigma, \alpha) = 0$ and I doubt it is possible to find $(\mu, \sigma, \alpha)$ satisfying all the equations (the number is infinite)!

Comment: @NN2 I agree that it's entirely possible that the setup is contradictory. I will run some numerical experiments

Comment: There are certainly some values of $\alpha$ for  which this is clearly impossible, since for example the variance of $Z$ is $\sigma^2 -\frac13\alpha^2$.  Also note the distributions of $Z-Y$ and $Z+Y$ are identical.

Comment: @Henry and NN2 I guess the conclusion is that there is no way around it: I have to solve the nasty integral for $p_Z(z)$ and see if I get something positive real valued.

Comment: “Note that $X$ and $Y$ are necessarily dependent” how do you figure this? One is a Gaussian and one is Uniform and you haven’t postulated any relationship between the two—the parameters aren’t even dependent! If you wrote, for example, $Y\sim \mathcal{U}(-X,X)$ conditional on $X$ then yes they are necessarily dependent, but as written, unless there is some missing context, there is no necessity that they depend on one another.

Comment: @NapD.Lover: $Y$ and $Z$ and independent and $X=Y+Z$ therefore $X$ and $Y$ are dependent as they are correlated.

Comment: It is not possible for $Y$ and $Z=X-Y$ to be independent. Assume to the contrary. Then $E(ZY)=E(Z)E(Y)=0$ implies $E(XY)=E(Y^2)=0.5 \alpha^2$. Consider the cases where $X$ and $Y$ are independent or dependent. The former case implies $E(X)E(Y)=\mu \cdot 0 = 0 = 0.5 \alpha^2$ a contradiction since $\alpha >0$. The latter case, implies $E(XY)=EE(XY|X)=E(X E(Y|X))=E(X \cdot 0)=0=0.5 \alpha^2$, another contradiction. Or have I made a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setup is not possible

We have
$$X = Y+Z$$

hence

$$\Phi_X(t) = \Phi_Y(t) \Phi_Z(t) $$

Because the first factor is a $sinc$ function, the product cannot be a gaussian.

Comment: In a comment, I said that it is impossible to construct X, Y and Z by using the $E(Y^n,(X-Y)^m)=0$. But I don't understand your answer (which seems to be a diffrent proof of the impossibility?). In fact, how do you know the product can't be gaussian? You don't know $W$, right?

Comment: @NN2 From my last equation, we should have $\Phi_Z(t) = \Phi_X(t) /\Phi_Y(t)$ which would have poles for several values. But any valid CF must be bounded https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Properties

Comment: Ok I get your idea.